# duplication using headers section in tableview using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

well I'm trying to add date to my header sections every time the user is done with his task. the problem is im kinda new with headers section and for some reason every time I add more than two tasks into the "Done" section, it seems like it duplicates itself.

have looked around stackOverFlow and couldn't find what I needed, and I hope u guys can help me up :)
Here's a pic of the app with the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERM8h.jpg

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

protocol TaskDelegate {
    func updateTaskName(name:String)
}

class TasksManViewController: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Sege: UISegmentedControl!
    
    
    
    var tasksArray = [Task](){
        didSet {
            // because we perform this operation on the main thread, it is safe
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    let isSwipeRightEnabled = true

    var delegate: TaskDelegate?

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        loadTasks()
    }

    
    
    // MARK: - DataSource + Delegate Methods:
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasksArray.count
    }
    
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tasksArray.count
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCellRow") as! SwipeTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = tasksArray[indexPath.row].title
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        if orientation == .left {
            
            guard isSwipeRightEnabled else { return nil }

            let doneAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) in
                
                //STEP1: Append the task to the doneTasksArr:
                self.tasksArray[indexPath.row].isDone = true
                
                //STEP3: Remove the Row:
                self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                
                //STEP4: Update the Model:
                self.saveTasks()
                
                self.delegate?.updateTaskName(name: "")
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
            
            let unDoneAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Undone") { (unDoneAction, indexPath) in
                self.tasksArray[indexPath.row].isDone = false
                
                self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                
                self.saveTasks()
                
            }
            
            
            //configure btn:
            doneAction.backgroundColor = .cyan
            unDoneAction.backgroundColor = .blue
            
            
            if Sege.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { //Doing this to allow the user to unDone tasks.
            return [doneAction]
            } else { return [unDoneAction] }

            
        } else {
            let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
                
                self.context.delete(self.tasksArray[indexPath.row])
                
                self.tasksArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                
                
                self.saveTasks()
                
                self.delegate?.updateTaskName(name: "")

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
            
            return [deleteAction]
        }
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Class Methods:
    @IBAction func addBtnTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        Sege.selectedSegmentIndex = 0 // Doing this to avoid the user to insert a task into the DoneTasks by mistake! and avoiad a bug :)
        insertNewTask()
    }
    
    
    
    func insertNewTask() {
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Task", message: "Please Add Your Task", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create New Task"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            
            let newItem = Task(context: self.context)
            
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            newItem.isDone = false
            newItem.date = Date()
            
            
            self.tasksArray.append(newItem)

            self.delegate?.updateTaskName(name: newItem.title!)
            
            self.saveTasks()
            
        }
        
        
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Sege Section:
    @IBAction func segeControlTapped(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        switch Sege.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            //Loading normal tasks whose are not done
            loadTasks()
            
        case 1:
            //Loading the doneTasks:
            loadDoneTasksFrom()

            
            
        default:
            print("There's something wrong with Sege!")
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let completedTasksToDisply = 0
        
        if Sege.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            if let firstTask = tasksArray[section].date {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: firstTask)
            
            return   " " + dateString + " " +  " " + "Completed Tasks: \(completedTasksToDisply)"
            }
            
        }
        
        
        return ""
}
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 13.0)
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    //MARK: - Model Manipulation Methods:
    func saveTasks() {
        do {
            try! context.save()
        } catch let err {
            print("Error Saving context \(err)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func loadTasks() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDone == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
        
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isDone", ascending: false)]
        
        do{
            tasksArray = try! context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("There was an error with loading items \(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    
    
    func loadDoneTasksFrom() {
        let request:NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDone == %@", NSNumber(value: true))
        
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isDone", ascending: false)]
        
        do{
            tasksArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from context\(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In `tableView(_ tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:)` shouldn't you test in which section you are instead of `Sege`?

Comment: You have a one-dimensional data source array and you are returning the number of items both in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections`. This cannot work. For sections you need a two-dimensional array or – preferable – a `Section` struct. And the `didSet` property observer for the data source array is not a good practice.

Comment: @vadian oh :\ my bad, will fix that. and ye I will try to learn more about that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Okay I see what you are trying to do. Give this a shot - we will need a double array - each array inside will have to be split by date - our query would look something like this:

```
var tasksArray = [[Task]]()
var sectionDates = [String]()

func loadTasks() {
    
    tasksArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    sectionDates.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isDone == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
        
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "isDone", ascending: false)]
        
    do{
        let tasks = try! context.fetch(request)

        for task in tasks {
             if let taskDate = task.date {
                
                 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                 let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: taskDate)
                 
                 if self.sectionDates.contains(dateString) {

                    if let section = self.sectionDates.firstIndex(of: dateString) {
                        self.tasksArray[section].append(task)
                    }
                    
                 } else {
                    self.sectionDates.append(dateString)

                    // EDIT - ADD THIS LINE (and self. where necessary)
                    self.tasksArray.append([])

                    if let section = self.sectionDates.firstIndex(of: dateString) {
                        self.tasksArray[section].append(task)
                    }
                 }
             }
        }

    } catch {
        print("There was an error with loading items \(error)")
    }
        
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Could also be helpful to load your objects in order but with this set up it should still group everything correctly regardless of the order - unless you want your sections in a specific order then you can specify in query

Now changes to your tableView delegate methods

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionDates.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasksArray[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCellRow") as! SwipeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = tasksArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
    
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let completedTasksToDisply = 0
        
    if Sege.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        let dateString = sectionDates[section]
        return   " " + dateString + " " +  " " + "Completed Tasks: \(completedTasksToDisply)"
    }
    return ""
}
```

I figured I'd leave the rest of the tableView delegate methods to you but for the most part we just need to identify the section before the indexPath row when working with the double array - as we did in cellForRow

I ran this code and this was the result:
[image]

Comment: @robots first of all thank you very much for your answer, second u got any tips that can lead me to do what I'm willing to? :) im kinda stuck cause its kinda hard for me to do a two-dimensional array when I don't need it :\

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @robots basically what im trying to accomplish is to be able to insert a date into the header according to the tasks that were done, for example if I've done 3 tasks so far today then it will be grouped together under the date title.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Check the updated answer. It should help get you in the right direction

Comment: @robots I'm trying it right now :) will update soon <3

Comment: @robots every time it reaches to "                            self.tasksArray[section].append(task)
" it says out of range :(

Comment: what do u think? :)

Comment: Sorry was on vacation - I ran the code and was missing one line:  tasksArray.append([]) - I will update my answer